# Canon Powershot SX260 HS problem

Tags: lens, error

The camera was in my handbag along with a bottle of water that I THOUGHT was tightly closed, but instead was dripping. Now the camera will not start without removing and re-inserting the rechargeable battery, and when it does start the lens telescopes in and out repeatedly and I get "Lens Error".  I've tried the tips for dislodging debris around the lens etc.  Any ideas or time for a new camera?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How best to repair water damage](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46772/how-best-to-repair-water-damage)

Answer (score 1):

The lens is probably not reacting to any physical issue blocking the lens' movement, but rather to an electronic issue with a sensor, or the signal path from such a sensor, that confirms position of the lens.

If it hasn't been very long since the camera was wet, try drying it out gently with the battery removed. You can do this by placing the camera in a container along with desiccant packets, which are readily available in most areas. The dollar store in my area carries [large desiccant packs](https://www.dollartree.com/the-home-store-moisture-eliminators-98oz/144947). Leave it in a closed container with desiccant for several days, then insert the fully charged battery and try the camera again.

Other than that, there's not much you can do at this point.

Just for future reference, any time electronic devices get wet, remove the battery immediately and do not replace it until the device is thoroughly dried. Most damage done to electronic devices when they are subjected to moisture is due to power following improper paths and overloading sensitive circuitry.